# WPF Image using DataTrigger with Storyboard throwing Cannot animate '((RenderTransform).(RotateTransform.Angle)' on an immutable object instance

Tags: c#, wpf

I want to use an image to show state and I want one of those images to be a loading spinner.  I'm rotating the image when its a spinner using a trigger.   However, this approach seems to throw the error "Cannot animate '(RenderTransform).(RotateTransform.Angle)' on an immutable object instance"

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding StatefulViewModels}" 
              HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel>
                <Expander IsEnabled="{Binding IsCompleted}">
                    <Expander.Header>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <Image Margin="5" Width="18">
                                <Image.RenderTransform>
                                    <RotateTransform Angle="0" CenterX="9" CenterY="9"/>
                                </Image.RenderTransform>
                                <Image.Style>
                                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Image}">
                                        <Style.Triggers>
                                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=CurrentState}" Value="{x:Static enums:State.CompletedWithErrors}">
                                                <Setter Property="Source" Value="../Images/Failed.png" />
                                            </DataTrigger>
                                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=CurrentState}" Value="{x:Static enums:State.CompletedSuccessfully}">
                                                <Setter Property="Source" Value="../Images/Success.png"/>
                                            </DataTrigger>
                                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=CurrentState}" Value="{x:Static enums:State.Unexecuted}">
                                                <Setter Property="Source" Value="../Images/Waiting.png"/>
                                            </DataTrigger>
                                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=CurrentState}" Value="{x:Static enums:State.Running}">
                                                <Setter Property="Source" Value="../Images/Running.png"/>
                                                <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                                                    <BeginStoryboard>
                                                        <Storyboard>
                                                            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="(RenderTransform).(RotateTransform.Angle)"
                                                                         From="0"
                                                                         To="360"
                                                                         Duration="0:0:2"
                                                                         RepeatBehavior="Forever"/>
                                                        </Storyboard>
                                                    </BeginStoryboard>
                                                </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                                                <DataTrigger.ExitActions>
                                                    <BeginStoryboard>
                                                        <Storyboard>
                                                            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="(RenderTransform).(RotateTransform.Angle)"
                                                                         To="0"
                                                                         Duration="0:0:0"/>
                                                        </Storyboard>
                                                    </BeginStoryboard>
                                                </DataTrigger.ExitActions>
                                            </DataTrigger>
                                        </Style.Triggers>
                                    </Style>
                                </Image.Style>
                            </Image>
                            <TextBlock Margin="5" Text="{Binding Path=Title}" FontSize="16"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </Expander.Header>
                    <ContentControl Content="{Binding}"  ContentTemplateSelector="{StaticResource ResultTemplateSelector}"/>
                </Expander>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

I've read an MSDN article [explaining about datatriggers and storyboards](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms742868(v=vs.85).aspx) but I can't think of a good alternative to this approach.

Whats the correct way to achieve this/fix my approach?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to set the RenderTransform property of the Image using a Style setter instead of setting it using a local value:

```
<Image Margin="5" Width="18">
    <Image.Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Image}">
            <Setter Property="RenderTransform">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <RotateTransform Angle="0" CenterX="9" CenterY="9"/>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=CurrentState}" Value="{x:Static enums:State.CompletedWithErrors}">
                    <Setter Property="Source" Value="../Images/Failed.png" />
                 </DataTrigger>
                 <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=CurrentState}" Value="{x:Static enums:State.CompletedSuccessfully}">
                    <Setter Property="Source" Value="../Images/Success.png"/>
                 </DataTrigger>
                 <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=CurrentState}" Value="{x:Static enums:State.Unexecuted}">
                    <Setter Property="Source" Value="../Images/Waiting.png"/>
                 </DataTrigger>
                 <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=CurrentState}" Value="{x:Static enums:State.Running}">
                    <Setter Property="Source" Value="/Images/Running.png"/>
                    <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                        <BeginStoryboard>
                            <Storyboard>
                                <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="(RenderTransform).(RotateTransform.Angle)"
                                                                         From="0"
                                                                         To="360"
                                                                         Duration="0:0:2"
                                                                         RepeatBehavior="Forever"/>
                            </Storyboard>
                        </BeginStoryboard>
                    </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                    <DataTrigger.ExitActions>
                        <BeginStoryboard>
                            <Storyboard>
                                <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="(RenderTransform).(RotateTransform.Angle)"
                                                                         To="0"
                                                                         Duration="0:0:0"/>
                            </Storyboard>
                        </BeginStoryboard>
                    </DataTrigger.ExitActions>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Image.Style>
</Image>
```

Comment: This works...  I don't really understand why though.  Could you elaborate at all?

Comment: There are several possible causes for this error message: https://wpftutorial.net/DebuggingAnimations.html. You can't for example animate the property and set it simultaneously. Your original code should work if there are no item with a CurrentState of Running initially.

Comment: Probably took me two hours to get here. Thanks @mm8.  Nailed it.